# How to declare IEnumerable in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, ienumerable

I want to know how to declare IEnumerable of unsigned type in C++/CLI managed code?
I have tried a lot of searching even came up on stack overflow but could not find anything that I could understand.

I am trying this:

```
IEnumerable^<unsigned int> msgs = client->GetMessage(uids, true, nullptr);
```

but it says there is no template.

Comment: If its template then for example : `IEnumerable<unsigned int>^`. You might also (probably) use `auto msgs`

Comment: Unlikely it says anything about "template".  Consider `auto msgs = client->GetMessage(...);`